# WPF ItemControl Virtualization, Items Visibility Issue

Tags: wpf, visibility, virtualization

I have an ItemControl that is virtualized and work perfectly. But when I change visibility of items from Visible to Collapsed and vice versa, it takes too long to rerender itemControl items.

```
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Grid.Row="1" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Margin="0,1,0,0">
                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="40" Style="{StaticResource RowGridStyle}" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityProperty}">
                                <!--Some UI Content-->
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

this XAML is work fine when i change ItemsSource (Persons) properties. Even if I change 1000 persons name, the UI changes fast.

BUT when the VisibilityProperty of 100 persons changes, the UI rerender too long.

Any helps ?

Comment: My guess is that when you collapse the grid you are just creating a 0 height `ItemContainer` and 100 containers with 0 height will easily fit in the ItemsControl so it has to instantiate all of them which means virtualization goes out the window. You are probably better off creating a filter and removing those items from the list.

Comment: @JasonBoyd Thanks a lot! Your guess is my answer. Then I calculate ItemsControl before rendering items.